# Codeigniter showing 404 Page Not Found on Hostgator

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, server

I'm currently testing my Codeigniter Project on my own Hostgator account. The project works well on my WAMP server but it shows a 404 Page Not Found error when online on Hostgator. I've tried playing around with the file permissions on FTP to playing around with the .htaccess file. The current site can be viewed here: www.test.jeffreyteruel.com.

Here's a look at my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My current file structure:

```
-application
-assets (css/js/img files) 
-cgi-bin(from the server) 
-system
-uploads
-.htaccess
-index.php
```

Here's my current config.php info:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://test.jeffreyteruel.com'; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

The default controller on the route.php file is: $route['default_controller'] = 'main';

Main Controller (main.php):

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
   class Main extends CI_Controller {
      public function __construct() 
      { 
         parent::__construct(); 
         //insert model here    
         $this->load->model('main_model'); 
         date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');       
       } 
      public function index()
      { 
        $content['main_content'] = 'home/home'; 
        $this->load->view('main',$content);
      } 
  ...  
  ?>
```

Any help to get the site showing properly would be appreciated.

Comment: If you go to `http://example.com/index.php` does that resolve correctly?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No. if I go to the link you mention I get this message: Example Domain

This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.

Comment: @jeffrey Teruel What Ohgodwhy meant was... if you go to http://test.jeffreyteruel.com/index.php what do you see? And as it's a live site we see you get the 404 page not found. http://jeffreyteruel.com/test/index.php gives the same result.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, I still get the same 404 error. Since it's a subdomain, I'll check if there's any difference if I put it on it's own domain.

Comment: What is your default route in routes.php. Do you have any upper case folder names? What happens if you disable your .htaccess and use the full links above?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw: $route['default_controller'] = 'main'; I just disabled my .htaccess file and I still get the same 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have CI running on a subdomain on Hostgator and I recall a slight struggle getting it working but as I'm old I've got a memory like a.... Hmmm can't remember!

My Simplified .htaccess is

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Addition:

In your config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://test.jeffreyteruel.com';
```

Add the trailing /

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://test.jeffreyteruel.com/';
```

UPDATE:

With Codeigniter 3 All Class names need to be Capitialized - First letter Uppercased ( ucfirst ).
Refer to :  [codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#file-naming](http://%20codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Comment: I do appreciate your help though.

Comment: Ok what happens if you change the config to $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: The clue is that http://test.jeffreyteruel.com/index.php results in a 404. That usually points to the default controller not being found which could be due to it's case. So can you shed some light on your main controller?

Comment: Just updated my code above with the route and main.php controller file for you and anyone reading this.

Comment: Thanks. Which version of CI are you using?

Comment: Codeigniter 3. I do appreciate you taking so much time with this.

Comment: Ok what happens if you rename your main.php to Main.php.

Comment: I now get an error that the main_model is not found. Just made the switch to Main_model.php and the homepage shows.

Comment: Grand  :) For your reference - http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I've been trying to work on this since last night.