# CodeIgniter: 404 Page Not Found on Hostgator

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've run into what seems to be a fairly common issue with CodeIgniter while working through [this tutorial](http://michaelsoriano.com/building-a-user-registration-system-part-1-new-user-form/). I keep receiving a 404 Page not Found error.

I've tried a variety of suggested solutions on the following questions but had absolutely no luck.

[CodeIgniter: 404 Page Not Found on Live Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709185/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-on-live-server)

[codeigniter not work at live page not found error on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315316/codeigniter-not-work-at-live-page-not-found-error-on-server)

[Codeigniter showing 404 Page Not Found on Hostgator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503934/codeigniter-showing-404-page-not-found-on-hostgator)

[CodeIgniter 404 Page Not Found On Godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472517/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-on-godaddy)

I can load the default welcome message in index.php, and if I copy the welcome message into main.php (and change the class name) everything works. My controller (Main.php) and model (User_model.php) are following the required first letter capitalization as well.

I've triple checked my filenames, tried all the suggested .htaccess files, and edited my config.php with no solution in site.

**Edit:** After trying @SarangaR and @dhruv jadia's suggestions, I continue to have the same issue. Here's the error log

```
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> Language Class Initialized
ERROR - 2016-02-11 21:29:39 --> 404 Page Not Found: Main/index
```

To be completely thorough, here is the code.

Controller - **Main.php**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

        public $status; 
        public $roles;

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('User_model', 'user_model', TRUE);
            $this->load->library('form_validation');    
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');
            $this->status = $this->config->item('status'); 
            $this->roles = $this->config->item('roles');
        }   


    public function register()
        {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'required');    
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');    

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {   
                $this->load->view('bootstrap/header');
                $this->load->view('register');
                $this->load->view('bootstrap/footer');
            }else{                
                if($this->user_model->isDuplicate($this->input->post('email'))){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', 'User email already exists');
                    redirect(site_url().'main/login');
                }else{

                    $clean = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
                    $id = $this->user_model->insertUser($clean); 
                    $token = $this->user_model->insertToken($id);                                        

                    $qstring = base64_encode($token);                    
                    $url = site_url() . 'main/complete/token/' . $qstring;
                    $link = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a>'; 

                    $message = '';                     
                    $message .= '<strong>You have signed up with our website</strong><br>';
                    $message .= '<strong>Please click:</strong> ' . $link;                          
                    echo $message; //send this in email
                    exit;


                };              
            }
        }
};
```

The Model - **User_model.php**

```
<?php 
class User_model extends CI_Model {
    public $status; 
    public $roles;    

    function __construct(){
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();        
        $this->status = $this->config->item('status');
        $this->roles = $this->config->item('roles');
    }

    public function insertUser($d)
    {  
            $string = array(
                'first_name'=>$d['firstname'],
                'last_name'=>$d['lastname'],
                'email'=>$d['email'],
                'role'=>$this->roles[0], 
                'status'=>$this->status[0]
            );
            $q = $this->db->insert_string('users',$string);             
            $this->db->query($q);
            return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function isDuplicate($email)
    {     
        $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email), 1);
        return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0 ? TRUE : FALSE;         
    }

    public function insertToken($user_id)
    {   
        $token = substr(sha1(rand()), 0, 30); 
        $date = date('Y-m-d');

        $string = array(
                'token'=> $token,
                'user_id'=>$user_id,
                'created'=>$date
            );
        $query = $this->db->insert_string('tokens',$string);
        $this->db->query($query);
        return $token;

    }
}
?>
```

The View - **register.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
    <h2>Hello There</h2>
    <h5>Please enter the required information below.</h5>     
<?php 
    $fattr = array('class' => 'form-signin');
    echo form_open('/main/register', $fattr); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
      <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'firstname', 'id'=> 'firstname', 'placeholder'=>'First Name', 'class'=>'form-control', 'value' => set_value('firstname'))); ?>
      <?php echo form_error('firstname');?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'lastname', 'id'=> 'lastname', 'placeholder'=>'Last Name', 'class'=>'form-control', 'value'=> set_value('lastname'))); ?>
      <?php echo form_error('lastname');?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <?php echo form_input(array('name'=>'email', 'id'=> 'email', 'placeholder'=>'Email', 'class'=>'form-control', 'value'=> set_value('email'))); ?>
      <?php echo form_error('email');?>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_submit(array('value'=>'Sign up', 'class'=>'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block')); ?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Finally, **config.php**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config['roles'] = array('subscriber', 'admin');
$config['status'] = array('pending', 'approved');
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| WARNING: You MUST set this value!
|
| If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
| your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production!
|
| If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
| a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
|
*/

$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.example.com/';
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/

$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
| 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
| 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
|
| WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
*/

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
| there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
| than english.
|
*/

$config['language'] = 'english';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Character Set
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
| that require a character set to be provided.
|
| See http://php.net/htmlspecialchars for a list of supported charsets.
|
*/

$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable/Disable System Hooks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you would like to use the 'hooks' feature you must enable it by
| setting this variable to TRUE (boolean).  See the user guide for details.
|
*/

$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Extension Prefix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item allows you to set the filename/classname prefix when extending
| native libraries.  For more information please see the user guide:
|
| https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
| https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
|
*/

$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Composer auto-loading
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Enabling this setting will tell CodeIgniter to look for a Composer
| package auto-loader script in application/vendor/autoload.php.
|
|   $config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
|
| Or if you have your vendor/ directory located somewhere else, you
| can opt to set a specific path as well:
|
|   $config['composer_autoload'] = '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
|
| For more information about Composer, please visit http://getcomposer.org/
|
| Note: This will NOT disable or override the CodeIgniter-specific
|   autoloading (application/config/autoload.php)
*/

$config['composer_autoload'] = '/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify which characters are permitted within your URLs.
| When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed characters they will
| get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| The configured value is actually a regular expression character group
| and it will be executed as: ! preg_match('/^[<permitted_uri_chars>]+$/i
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable Query Strings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
| example.com/who/what/where/
|
| By default CodeIgniter enables access to the $_GET array.  If for some
| reason you would like to disable it, set 'allow_get_array' to FALSE.
|
| You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
| example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
|
| Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
| The other items let you set the query string 'words' that will
| invoke your controllers and its functions:
| example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
|
| Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
| this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
| use segment based URLs.
|
*/
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| You can also pass an array with threshold levels to show individual error types
|
|   array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/

$config['log_threshold'] = 0;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/logs/ directory. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/

$config['log_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log File Extension
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The default filename extension for log files. The default 'php' allows for
| protecting the log files via basic scripting, when they are to be stored
| under a publicly accessible directory.
|
| Note: Leaving it blank will default to 'php'.
|
*/

$config['log_file_extension'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Log File Permissions
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The file system permissions to be applied on newly created log files.
|
| IMPORTANT: This MUST be an integer (no quotes) and you MUST use octal
|            integer notation (i.e. 0700, 0644, etc.)
*/

$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Date Format for Logs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Each item that is logged has an associated date. You can use PHP date
| codes to set your own date formatting
|
*/

$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Views Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/views/errors/ directory.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|

*/

$config['error_views_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/cache/ directory.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|

*/

$config['cache_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Include Query String
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Whether to take the URL query string into consideration when generating
| output cache files. Valid options are:
|
|   FALSE      = Disabled
|   TRUE       = Enabled, take all query parameters into account.
|                Please be aware that this may result in numerous cache
|                files generated for the same page over and over again.
|   array('q') = Enabled, but only take into account the specified list
|                of query parameters.
|

*/

$config['cache_query_string'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you use the Encryption class, you must set an encryption key.
| See the user guide for more info.
|
| https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html
|

*/

$config['encryption_key'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'sess_driver'
|
|   The storage driver to use: files, database, redis, memcached
|
| 'sess_cookie_name'
|
|   The session cookie name, must contain only [0-9a-z_-] characters
|
| 'sess_expiration'
|
|   The number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed.
|
| 'sess_save_path'
|
|   The location to save sessions to, driver dependent.
|
|   For the 'files' driver, it's a path to a writable directory.
|   WARNING: Only absolute paths are supported!
|
|   For the 'database' driver, it's a table name.
|   Please read up the manual for the format with other session drivers.
|
|   IMPORTANT: You are REQUIRED to set a valid save path!
|
| 'sess_match_ip'
|
|   Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data.
|
|   WARNING: If you're using the database driver, don't forget to update
|            your session table's PRIMARY KEY when changing this setting.
|
| 'sess_time_to_update'
|
|   How many seconds between CI regenerating the session ID.
|
| 'sess_regenerate_destroy'
|
|   Whether to destroy session data associated with the old session ID
|   when auto-regenerating the session ID. When set to FALSE, the data
|   will be later deleted by the garbage collector.
|
| Other session cookie settings are shared with the rest of the application,
| except for 'cookie_prefix' and 'cookie_httponly', which are ignored here.
|

*/

$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';

$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';

$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;

$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;

$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix'   = Set a cookie name prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain'   = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'     = Typically will be a forward slash
| 'cookie_secure'   = Cookie will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
| 'cookie_httponly' = Cookie will only be accessible via HTTP(S) (no javascript)
|
| Note: These settings (with the exception of 'cookie_prefix' and
|       'cookie_httponly') will also affect sessions.
|

*/

$config['cookie_prefix']    = '';

$config['cookie_domain']    = '';

$config['cookie_path']      = '/';

$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;

$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Standardize newlines
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether to standardize newline characters in input data,
| meaning to replace \r\n, \r, \n occurrences with the PHP_EOL value.
|
| This is particularly useful for portability between UNIX-based OSes,
| (usually \n) and Windows (\r\n).
|

*/

$config['standardize_newlines'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global XSS Filtering
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
| COOKIE data is encountered
|
| WARNING: This feature is DEPRECATED and currently available only
|          for backwards compatibility purposes!
|

*/

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross Site Request Forgery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
| checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
| recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
|
| 'csrf_token_name' = The token name
| 'csrf_cookie_name' = The cookie name
| 'csrf_expire' = The number in seconds the token should expire.
| 'csrf_regenerate' = Regenerate token on every submission
| 'csrf_exclude_uris' = Array of URIs which ignore CSRF checks

*/

$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;

$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';

$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';

$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;

$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;

$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Output Compression
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Enables Gzip output compression for faster page loads.  When enabled,
| the output class will test whether your server supports Gzip.
| Even if it does, however, not all browsers support compression
| so enable only if you are reasonably sure your visitors can handle it.
|
| Only used if zlib.output_compression is turned off in your php.ini.
| Please do not use it together with httpd-level output compression.
|
| VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it
| means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
| even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  For
| compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
| by the output class.  Do not 'echo' any values with compression enabled.
|

*/

$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Master Time Reference
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Options are 'local' or any PHP supported timezone. This preference tells
| the system whether to use your server's local time as the master 'now'
| reference, or convert it to the configured one timezone. See the 'date
| helper' page of the user guide for information regarding date handling.
|

*/

$config['time_reference'] = 'local';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Rewrite PHP Short Tags
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
| can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
| in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
| Note: You need to have eval() enabled for this to work.
|

*/

$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Reverse Proxy IPs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy
| IP addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust headers such as
| HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_CLIENT_IP in order to properly identify
| the visitor's IP address.
|
| You can use both an array or a comma-separated list of proxy addresses,
| as well as specifying whole subnets. Here are a few examples:
|
| Comma-separated:  '10.0.1.200,192.168.5.0/24'
| Array:        array('10.0.1.200', '192.168.5.0/24')

*/

$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

Comment: Did you check this line?  $this->load->model('User_model', 'user_model', TRUE); try to change  user_model to User_model

Comment: @SarangaR Sadly, that wasn't it. Still receiving the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

change line of config.php file from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.example.com/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

and also change line of routes.php file from

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
```

to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Main';
```